# Tilemill Legend not displaying title and only filling in 5 out of 9 categories

Tags: tilemill

Tilemill Legend not displaying title and only filling in 5 out of 9 categories.

Here's the code

[image]

Actual look of the legend

[image]

Comment: For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) ***as text***.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Answer (score 1):

It is a css issue. 
For the title you have to modify wax-legend class.
For example:

```
.wax-legend {
max-width: 400px !important;
text-align: left;  
font-size: 100%;  
margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

For colours matter, I have a 14 categories working like a charm as this:

```
<div class="my-legend">  
<div class="legend-title">Salubridad de la Vegetacion</div>  
<div class="legend-scale">  
<ul class="legend-labels">  
<li><span style="background:#FF0014;"></span>Quemado</li>  
<li><span style="background:#F70917;"></span>-</li>  
<li><span style="background:#F0121B;"></span>-</li>  
<li><span style="background:#E91C1F;"></span>-</li>  
<li><span style="background:#E22522;"></span>-</li>  
<li><span style="background:#DA2F26;"></span>-</li>  
<li><span style="background:#D3382A;"></span>-</li>  
<li><span style="background:#A17A44;"></span>-</li>  
<li><span style="background:#928D4B;"></span>-</li>  
<li><span style="background:#8B974F;"></span>-</li>  
<li><span style="background:#7DAA56;"></span>-</li>  
<li><span style="background:#6EBC5E;"></span>-</li>  
<li><span style="background:#58D969;"></span>Saludable</li>     
<li><span style="background:#43F574;"></span>.</li>  
</ul>  
</div>  
<div class="legend-source">Fuente: <a href="http://www.lynxmonitoreo.com.ar/">Lynx     Monitoreo</a></div>  
</div>  
<style type="text/css">  
.wax-legend {
max-width: 400px !important;
text-align: left;  
font-size: 100%;  
margin-bottom:10px;
}  
.legend-title{  
text-align: center;
text-transform:uppercase;  
margin-bottom: 8px;  
font-weight: bold;  
font-size: 90%;  
}  
.wax-legend .legend-scale ul {  
margin: 0;  
padding: 0;  
float: left;  
list-style: none;

}  
.wax-legend .legend-scale ul li {  
display: block;  
float: left;  
width: 25px;  
margin-bottom: 6px;  
text-align: center;  
font-size: 70%;  
list-style: none;  
}  
.wax-legend ul.legend-labels li span {  
display: block;  
float: left;  
height: 15px;  
width: 25px;  
}  
.wax-legend .legend-source {  
font-size: 70%;  
color: #999;  
clear: both;
text-align:right;
}  
.wax-legend a {  
color: #777;  
}  
}  
</style>
```